# Dismiss some views

Tags: iphone

First, sorry about my English, I know it's bad, but I'm trying to make it better...
Here is the issue: I'm making an app, with a view controller, with a lot of views... I want to make a button to go back to the main one. I think I have to dismiss the views I pushed. I dont know if that is necessary or if I can push it again directly. If it is, how can I do that? I've tried to put a dismiss method after the presentModalViewController one, but it didn't work.
Any help?
Thank you so much for your help ;)

Comment: I.m working with delegates now, but I have a question now:
To dismiss more than one modal views, Can I dismiss all of them at a time, dismissing the main one? or instead I have to dismiss one by one, nesting them... Again, sorry for my English

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To present and dismiss a modal view you'll have to use delegation.

Here is an explanation for how to present and dismiss [modal views](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/ModalViewControllers/ModalViewControllers.html).

Modal views are handled differently than views controlled by the UINavigationController or UITabBarController, which just push them onto a view stack or array of views.

Answer (score 1):

It hard to tell from your question, but you may be confused by the navigation stack and the modal controllers.

A modal controller gets presented and dismissed using:

```
presentModalViewController:animated:
dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:
```

Navigation controllers are pushed and popped using:

```
pushViewController:animated:
popViewControllerAnimated:
```

So make sure you are using the correct method to pop or dismiss the view in question.

Comment: In this case I'm using, presentModalViewController:animated: and dismissModal ViewController:animated: but I had the same problem with push&pop.Thank you